# How to scale a double like 1.9416746607144E+36 down so I can use in a winForms chart?

Tags: c#, charts, double, windows-forms-designer

I have an double array of numbers including the following and many more in the similar range.

1.9416746607144E+36, 3.35084834769439E+35, 1.61781076604004E+36, 4.4117087319933E+35, 1.53778814885709E+36, 6.71296251346301E+35, 1.20117826215991E+36 and so on.

How can I scale these down so I can use them to draw a windows forms chart?

I have tryed scaling down by using the following:

```
    public static double SetSigFigs(double d, int digits)
    {
        double scale = Math.Pow(10, Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(d))) + 1);

        return scale * Math.Round(d / scale, digits);
    }
```

This does nothing to the numbers.

Comment: Actually doubles can go to E+308

Comment: The chart control has been around for a very long time, well before Microsoft purchased it.  Graphics was always traditionally done in float, still is in many places.  You never want to get close to float.MaxValue, scaling and translating it yourself is the obvious workaround.

Comment: Do you know any methods to scale down?

Comment: I have tryed rounding but it does nothing

Comment: Divide everything by a constant, such as 1E+34 or 1E+35.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of mapping the range [0:10e36] onto the range [0:1]  (or whichever concordant system you want.)

The first question you should be asking is:
what do values that big actually represent, and if i have 1e24, 1e34 and 1e36 as 'Legitimate' values what would i like to see on the chart.

The simplest answer is in the comment by dbugger above with a simple division to rescale the range, but depending on your use case (very few things end up with a legitimate number that large, check for underflow or almost-div-0 errors) then a rescaling function like log(x) , or x^(1/4)/10e6 re-scaling functions may be more appropriate.

There are only 7.1e9 people on earth, earth weighs [5.98*10e24 kg](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=weight%20of%20the%20earth&lk=4&num=1), the universe is expected to be in existence around 3e20 milliseconds (10 billion years), and there are also [approx 10e20 stars in the universe](http://www.universetoday.com/102630/how-many-stars-are-there-in-the-universe/).

The point is 10e36 does not represent any type of phsyical thing, so perhaps working out what you are trying to plot will aid you in describing how to convert those numbers into a sensible plotting range.